# gRPC/protobuf design pattern for RPC call involving mix of fixed and large repeated fields?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Is there a good pattern for sending a large dataset using gRPC and protocol buffers that has a mix of some header data, and some large repeated data?

E.g. for a server that accepts a matrix generated by some other process as input, a service and message might look as follows:

```
service MatrixService {
    rpc DoSomething(stream Matrix) returns (stream Matrix) {}
}

message Matrix {
    uint32 num_rows = 1;
    uint32 num_cols = 2;
    string created_by = 3;
    string creation_parameters = 4;
    repeated float data = 5;
}
```

It's really only the `data` field that is large enough to require streaming, the rest of the parameters are just headers that the server only needs to receive once.

Is there some commonly used pattern for efficiently making gRPC request that contains some initial header information, and a large amount of repeated data?

Should `oneOf` be used in cases like this (i.e. splitting the `Matrix` message into a `oneOf { MatrixHeader, MatrixData }`?

Or is it typically more common to just set the header fields on the first request, and leave them blank by convention in subsequent requests?

Or are there some other solutions that I've not considered?

Comment: Could you at least elaborate on your vote https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26036971

Comment: that is at least good to hear, I really thought I must completely not understand what is good anymore (as in on SO)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider chunking your data. See [gRPC + Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969446/grpc-image-upload/34982660).
Also, note that the maximum receive message size is [4 MB by default](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h#L447). You can increase it by setting the channel argument [GRPC_ARG_MAX_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_LENGTH](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h#L153)

Comment: Thanks, that answer has a lot of info, will flag this question as a duplicate.