# Why do you use `stream` for GRPC/protobuf file transfers?

Tags: stream, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've seen a couple examples like this:

```
service Service{
  rpc updload(stream Data) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {};
  rpc download(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream Data) {};
}

message Data { bytes bytes = 1; }
```

What is the purpose of using `stream`, does it make the transfer more efficient?

In theory - yes - I obviously wan't to stream my file transfers but that's what happens over a connection... So, what is the actual benefit to this keyword, does it enforce some form of special buffering to reduce some overhead? Either way, the data is being transmitted, in full!

Answer (score 2):

It's more efficient because, within a **single** call, multiple messages may be sent.

This avoids, not only re-establishing another (hopefully TLS i.e. even more work) connection with the server but also avoids spinning up client and server "stubs"; both the client and server are ready for more messages.

It's somewhat similar to being connected on a telephone call with your friend who, before hanging up, says "Oh, another thing...". Instead of hanging up the call and then, 5 minutes later, calling you back, interrupting dinner and causing you to pause a movie.

Comment: So, this essentially keeps open a long-lived connection to reduce connection-instantiation overhead. What if I'm just sending 1-off messages, and not sending multiple requests in series. Would it keep open a redundant stream, or would it eventually time out?

Comment: I recommend you review the content in grpc.io where much of this is described: https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very similar to the [gRPC + Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982660/4690866) question, although from a different perspective.

Doing a large download (10+ MB) as a single response message puts strong limits on the size of that download, as the entire response message is sent and processed at once. For most use cases, it is much better to chunk a 100 MB file into 1-10 MB chunks than require all 100 MB to be in memory at once. That also allows the downloader to begin processing the file before the entire file is acquired which reduces processing latency.

Without streaming, chunking would require multiple RPCs, which are annoying to coordinate and have performance complications. Because there is latency to complete RPCs, for reasonable performance you either have to do many RPCs in parallel (but how many?) or have a large batch size (but how big?). Multiple RPCs can also hit colder application caches, as each RPC goes to a different backend.

Using streaming provides the same throughput as the non-chunking approach without as many headaches of normal chunking approaches. Since streaming is pipelined (server can start sending next chunk as soon as previous chunk is sent) there's no added per-chunk latency between the client and server. This makes it much easier to choose a chunk size, as there is a wide range of "reasonable" sizes that will behave similarly and the system will naturally react as network performance varies.

While sending a message on an existing stream has less overhead than creating a new RPC, for many users the difference is negligible and it is generally better to structure your RPCs in a way that is architecturally beneficial to your application and not just to eek out small optimizations in gRPC. The reason to use the stream in this case is to make *your application* perform better at lower complexity.